Using FlashSwap with Uniswap swapping functions like 'swapExactETHForTokens'
I tried taking a loan from Uniswapv2 Flash swap. After taking the loan successfully, I tried making a swap on the uniswap v2 using the swapExactTokensForTokens function then I got this error "Error: reverted with reason string 'UniswapV2: LOCKED'". I understand this error is as a result of UniswapV2 reentrancy guard trying to prevent calling the two swap functions in the same transaction Since the flashswap uses the 'swap' function to take these loans. My question now is this, is it not possible to call the swapExactTokensForTokens function right after calling the flashswap function.
